# Kick to the jaw injury rehabilitation

Tags: boxing, injury, kickboxing, kicking, medical-advice

Recently I got a really hard and clean round house kick on my jaw. Almost KOed me entirely. The jaw-ear junction immediately swell and had my internal ear also aching.

What I did was taking 2 pills diclofenac 10 or less minutes after impact and apply cold to the jaw-ear junction. Inflammation went down after 1 hr approximately. 4 days after I still feel a bit of ache when biting hard.

Is there a recommended therapy or rehabilitation for this kind of lesions?

Comment: Frankly, I say see a doctor for this to ensure that you don't have any sort of lasting injury from this.

Comment: Were you prescribed the diclofenac for your jaw? If not, why would you take it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A broken or dislocated jaw usually heals well after treatment. But the jaw may become dislocated again in the future.

In the US, Columbia University, College of Dental Medicine has done some pioneering work in treatment & therapies related to jaw injuries. So it would be a good idea to touch base with their medical experts.

Your doctor will diagnose a jaw break or dislocation with a physical examination and an X-ray. So by all means visit your nearest medical center ASAP.